# Javascript returning Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I have a facebook friend invite sender and the following code is returning and error.

```
iframeHTML = $myjq('#polldaddy_embed_0').html();
                          if (iframeHTML.indexOf("facebook") === -1) {
                              iframeHTML = iframeHTML.replace("fb_id=","fb_id="+window.uid);
                              iframeHTML = iframeHTML.replace("?q_3826051_url=","&q_3826051_url="+encodeURIComponent(window.url));
                              $myjq('#polldaddy_embed_0').html(iframeHTML);
                          if (window.total>=5) {
                               $myjq('#fb_first5_id').trigger('click');
                          }
                       }
```

The error which I am getting is:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tells you that the element with the `id` `polldaddy_embed_0` didn't exist when that code ran. If you call `$()` with a selector that doesn't match anything, you get an empty jQuery set; if you call `html` on an empty jQuery set, you get back `undefined`, which you're storing in your `iframeHTML` variable. Then you try to call `indexOf` using that variable, and you get the error.